# Why does cfdisk give me an "Unsupported GPT" error?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          409599   199.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2          409600       608667647   290.0 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   3       608667648       616859647   3.9 GiB     8200  Linux swap
   5      1026465792      1250263039   106.7 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   6       616863744       770463743   73.2 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   7       770463744       771078143   300.0 MiB   EF02  Linux filesystem
   8       924067840      1026463743   48.8 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   9       771078144       924067839   73.0 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
```

Is what gdisk says my computer looks like (well /dev/sda, but you know.) Anyway no matter which operating system I use etc every time cfdisk refuses to let me edit my hard drive why? It always returns an error which is  Warning!!  `Unsupported GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected. Use GNU Parted`. Anyway the command I am running is `sudo cfdisk /dev/sda` which I think is proper for editing the /dev/sda partitions. Anyway any idea as to how to stop this without completely reformatting my hard drive b/c I don't like gdisk that much.

Comment: The problem I face is with a live cd.

Comment: Yes I am as of an edit 6 minutes ago I added that info.

Comment: @SamMercier: sorry, your edit clarified it. Simple solution: replace *f* with *g* and **use `cgdisk`** (answer edited too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to have a GPT partition table and *cfdisk* will NOT work with those (only MBR supported). **Please use `cgdisk` instead :)**

#### Normal usage of *cgdisk* on GPT hard disks

Just start it as `sudo cgdisk`, and you can interactively perform operations. If you have a desktop or X installed, a GUI alternative such as *gparted* may be preferable.

[image]

Comment: Sorry my first post was unclear I just edited it. Hopefully that will make my problem more clear. Okay thanks I am kind of new to partitioning in the command line.